# select clause where ids are in a json array

Tags: postgresql

I have a json array of `uuids` in string form and I'd like to use it in a select query:

```
SELECT "Animals" WHERE "id" = jsonb_array_elements_text(
'["2ffae132-7a46-11eb-8be3-a483e71a4d0b",
  "2ffae132-7a46-11eb-8be3-a483e71a4d0c",
  "2ffae132-7a46-11eb-8be3-a483e71a4d0d"]');
```

gives this error

```
ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE
LINE 1: ...* from "Animals" WHERE "id" = jsonb_arra...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 0A000
Character: 58
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use a set-returning function, you'll need to do a sub-`SELECT`:

```
edb=# create table animals (id text, name text);
CREATE TABLE
edb=# insert into animals values ('2ffae132-7a46-11eb-8be3-a483e71a4d0b','foo');
INSERT 0 1
edb=# SELECT * from animals WHERE "id" in (select jsonb_array_elements_text(
'["2ffae132-7a46-11eb-8be3-a483e71a4d0b",
  "2ffae132-7a46-11eb-8be3-a483e71a4d0c",
  "2ffae132-7a46-11eb-8be3-a483e71a4d0d"]'));
                  id                  | name 
--------------------------------------+------
 2ffae132-7a46-11eb-8be3-a483e71a4d0b | foo
(1 row)
```